# Let $A={a_1, a_2, ..., a_n}$ and $B={b_1, b_2, ..., b_n}$ be bases for V: is it true that there exists (see included)

Tags: linear-algebra

a) some vector $b_j$ in B such that $b_j$ does not belong to $\text{Span}(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)?$

b) some vector $b_j$ and $b_k$ in B such that $b_j$ $(b_j,b_k,a_3,...,a_n)$ is a basis for $V$?

I got both of them as yes.

Im not too sure on the first one but my logic for the second is that:

Since $\dim (A) = \dim (B)$, you can append any vector from one basis as long as the number of vectors equals $n$.

Answer (score 2):

a) Yes.  The orthogonal complement of $\text{span}(a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n)$ will be non-empty.  Let $v$ be a member of this orthogonal complement.  Note that $v\in V$.  Project each $b$ onto $v$.  For any $b$ in which this projection results in a non-zero vector is not in $\text{span}(a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n)$.

b)  $b_j$ is always in the $\text{span}(b_j,b_k,a_3,\ldots,a_n)$. In fact, $b_j$ is in $\text{span}(b_j)$.  You don't even need the other vectors.